# Powershell Changing Directory

Tags: powershell

Ok i have very basic question and stackoverflow struggles me with formatting. I tried several links for changing windows powershell directory to another one but it always gives error like in this link;

[enter link description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yqNRH.jpg)

Primarily this:

```
Set-Location -Path C:\Program Files
```

produces

> Set-Location: A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts the argument 'Files'.

Comment: Quotes worked, thank you!

Comment: I see you're kinda new here. Don't mark the title with "Resolved", "Solved" or similar modifiers. I will put my comment into an answer and you can tick the check mark next it to mark it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several different errors there. I think the main thing you are missing is that if the path has a space, you need to put quotes around it. Either single or double quotes will work.